# Basic I/O performance in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc

Another microbenchmark: Why is this "loop" (compiled with `ghc -O2 -fllvm`, 7.4.1, Linux 64bit 3.2 kernel, redirected to `/dev/null`)

```
mapM_ print [1..100000000]
```

about 5x slower than a simple for-cycle in plain `C` with `write(2)` non-buffered syscall? I am trying to gather Haskell gotchas.

*Even this slow C solution is much faster than Haskell*

```
int i;
char buf[16];
for (i=0; i<=100000000; i++) {
    sprintf(buf, "%d\n", i);
    write(1, buf, strlen(buf));
}
```

Comment: Is this sentence *simple for-cycle in plain C with write(2) non-buffered syscall* easier to write and understand then the actual code?

Comment: use `ByteString`s for printing. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring

Comment: @n.m. For anybody, who can answer this question, the C code is obvious and completely useless.

Comment: Show the C code. It's _not_ obvious. There are several possibilities.

Comment: I refactored your code to `let xs = unlines $ map show [1..100000000] in return ()`. It achieves the same effect but runs much faster.

Comment: I think that no effect is not equivalent to writing to a handle, even if that handle is being redirected somewhere worthless.

Comment: @AndrewC While I agree with you, I'd like to point out that these questions help newbies like me drill these small things into our heads.

Comment: @gphilip I'm interested: What small things did you learn from the question?

Comment: @AndrewC One example would be: `putStr . unlines $ map show [0 :: Int .. 100000000]` as a faster way of doing the same thing, which I doubt I would have thought up by myself, but which I can understand once I see it. Also: while I knew that `Integer` involved more overheads than `Int`, the use of "boxed" in the answers is still mysterious to me. So: one more thing to read up on. Once the number of times I see this usage crosses a certain threshold, I will look it up and learn it. And so on.

Comment: @gphilip Good, but you didn't mention the most important performance issue: __Don't__ use screen IO to do file IO. It's almost incomparably slower. In C _and_ haskell screen IO are _way_ too fast for humans anyway, but way too slow for disks. Martin's questions perpetuate the novice's myth that minor speed tweaks are good whilst it's OK to ignore the most significant and important algorithmic improvements. He wants to save seconds whilst losing minutes, but using library functions where speed doesn't matter anyway. I think it harms some novices; you could ask a much less misleading question.

Comment: @AndrewC neither of these programs open any screen device. These are just as much pipe I/O as screen I/O and we need obvious easy pipe I/O programs to be fast.

Comment: @andrewC please offer your answer in the answers section, not the comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, on my box the C code, compiled per `gcc -O3` takes about 21.5 seconds to run, the original Haskell code about 56 seconds. So not a factor of 5, a bit above 2.5.

The first nontrivial difference is that

```
mapM_ print [1..100000000]
```

uses `Integer`s, that's a bit slower because it involves a check upfront, and then works with boxed `Int`s, while the `Show` instance of `Int` does the conversion work on unboxed `Int#`s.

Adding a type signature, so that the Haskell code works on `Int`s,

```
mapM_ print [1 :: Int .. 100000000]
```

brings the time down to 47 seconds, a bit above twice the time the C code takes.

Now, another big difference is that `show` produces a linked list of `Char` and doesn't just fill a contiguous buffer of bytes. That is slower too.

Then that linked list of `Char`s is used to fill a byte buffer that then is written to the `stdout` handle.

So, the Haskell code does more, and more complicated things than the C code, thus it's not surprising that it takes longer.

Admittedly, it would be desirable to have an easy way to output such things more directly (and hence faster). However, the proper way to handle it is to use a more suitable algorithm (that applies to C too). A simple change to

```
putStr . unlines $ map show [0 :: Int .. 100000000]
```

almost halves the time taken, and if one wants it really fast, one uses the faster `ByteString` I/O and builds the output efficiently as exemplified in [applicative's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13340501/1011995).

Comment: It would be desirable, but then, printing numbers to text is _in principle_ not optimal anyway. For really high throughput, one needs binary storage in Haskell as well as in C, and `Data.Binary` is really quite nicely fast.

Comment: That's true. But sometimes you want to output text nevertheless, and it would be nice if there were more easy options to make that faster (though I have never really needed that, I don't do much I/O).

Answer (score 8):

On my (rather slow and outdated) machine the results are:

```
$ time haskell-test > haskell-out.txt
real    1m57.497s
user    1m47.759s
sys     0m9.369s
$ time c-test > c-out.txt
real    7m28.792s
user    1m9.072s
sys     6m13.923s
$ diff haskell-out.txt c-out.txt
$
```

(I have fixed the list so that both C and Haskell start with 0).

Yes you read this right. Haskell is several times faster than C. Or rather, normally buffered Haskell is faster than C with write(2) non-buffered syscall.

(When measuring output to /dev/null instead of a real disk file, C is about 1.5 times faster, but who cares about /dev/null performance?)

Technical data: Intel E2140 CPU, 2 cores, 1.6 GHz, 1M cache, Gentoo Linux, gcc4.6.1, ghc7.6.1.

Comment: Excellent real-world point. So if I want to print to file, I'll use haskell, but I'll be sure to use C for all my print-to-`/dev/null` needs.

Answer (score 5):

The standard Haskell way to hand giant bytestrings over to the operating system is to use a builder monoid.

```
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Builder  -- requires bytestring-0.10.x
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Builder.ASCII -- omit for bytestring-0.10.2.x
import Data.Monoid
import System.IO

main = hPutBuilder stdout $ build  [0..100000000::Int]

build = foldr add_line mempty
   where add_line n b = intDec n <> charUtf8 '\n' <> b
```

which gives me:

```
 $ time ./printbuilder >> /dev/null
 real   0m7.032s
 user   0m6.603s
 sys    0m0.398s
```

in contrast to Haskell approach you used

```
$ time ./print >> /dev/null
real    1m0.143s
user    0m58.349s
sys 0m1.032s
```

That is, it's child's play to do nine times better than  `mapM_ print`, contra Daniel Fischer's suprising defeatism. Everything you need to know is here: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/0.10.2.0/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Builder.html I won't compare it with your C since my results were much slower than Daniel's and n.m. so I figure something was going wrong.

Edit: Made the imports consistent with all versions of `bytestring-0.10.x` It occurred to me the following might be clearer -- the `Builder` equivalent of `unlines . map show`:

```
main = hPutBuilder stdout $ unlines_ $ map intDec [0..100000000::Int]
 where unlines_ = mconcat . map (<> charUtf8 '\n')
```

Comment: I can't compile your solution, is it OK? Where's `intDec` from?

Comment: it's from `Data.ByteString.Builder`. Looking into it now, things have been reshuffled with the latest release; if you have any version of `bytestring-0-10` replacing that line with `import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Builder; import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Builder.ASCII` should work.