# Haskell algorithm advice and suggestions for alternate solutions

Tags: performance, algorithm, haskell

I'm leaving the description of the problem below, but I'm editing out all of the irrelevant bits as I go.

1) Thanks to dfeuer, I've been able to shed almost a full second off this program. I got down to 9.2 seconds from 10.1.

2) Thanks to a modification of what SO user [applicative posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334074/basic-i-o-performance-in-haskell), I was able to get down to 7.0 seconds, rendering IO as being very efficient.

3) Thanks to a different version of groupBy found [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/List_function_suggestions#Generalize_groupBy_and_friends), I'm now at 6.2 seconds.

4) A re-implemention of the builder output and now at 5.8 seconds.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Builder    as BB  
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as DB
import qualified Data.Function              as DF

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Monoid
import System.IO

groupBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupBy rel []     = []
groupBy rel (x:xs) = (x:ys) : groupBy rel zs
    where (ys,zs) = groupByAux x xs
          groupByAux x0 (x:xs) 
              | rel x0 x = (x:ys, zs)
              where (ys,zs) = groupByAux x xs
          groupByAux y xs = ([], xs)

filterLengthBy :: (Int -> Bool) -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
filterLengthBy fn = filter (flb fn)
    where flb fn xs = fn $ length xs  

buildOutput x y =  BB.intDec x <> BB.char7 ' ' <> BB.intDec y <> BB.char7 '\n'

tensAndHundreds :: [[[Int]]] -> [BB.Builder]
tensAndHundreds [] = []
tensAndHundreds (x:xs) 
    | length x /= 10 = tens x ++ tensAndHundreds xs
    | otherwise      = buildOutput (head $ head x) 100 : tensAndHundreds xs

tens :: [[Int]] -> [BB.Builder]
tens = foldr (\x acc -> buildOutput (head x) 10 : acc) []

dbIntVals :: DB.ByteString -> [Int]
dbIntVals xs = 
    case (DB.readInt xs) of
         Just (x', xs') -> x' : dbIntVals (DB.tail xs')
         Nothing        -> if xs == DB.empty
                           then []
                           else dbIntVals (DB.tail xs)

generateResults :: [Int] -> [BB.Builder]
generateResults xs = tensAndHundreds 
                   $ groupBy ((==) `DF.on` (`quot` 100) . head) 
                   $ filterLengthBy (== 10)
                   $ groupBy ((==) `DF.on` (`quot` 10)) xs

displayResults :: [BB.Builder] -> IO ()
displayResults xs = BB.hPutBuilder stdout $ mconcat xs

main :: IO ()
main = DB.getContents >>= 
       displayResults . generateResults . dbIntVals
```

**My two questions that were on the bottom of the original post are:**

1. Given the approach that I posted above, is there anything that I missed that would improve the efficiency of and consequently the performance of this program? Is the space allocation the final bottleneck? In other words, did the groupBy method run its course?
2. What other ways could I look at this problem that would improve efficiency while still attempting to avoid counters in the traditional sense? I'm not yet experienced with the advance features of Haskell, but please feel free to offer pointers.

**This is the original problem. I left the first version of the code, but removed all of the profiler stuff**

I started to learn Haskell (again) and decided to try out some random problems that I found. One problem that I worked out from the Arch Linux forums goes like this:

Given a set of unique, ascending, but not necessarily continuous integers, for every potential sub-range of 100 starting at 0 (0-99, 100-199, 1300-1399, etc), if that sub-range has all 100 elements, print the head value followed by 100:

```
0 100
145600 100
```

Otherwise, for every continuous set of 10 over the same range starting at 0 (0-9, 10-19, 15430-15439, etc), print the head of that range followed by 10:

```
30 10
70 10
145620 10 
145650 10
```

An example output from a tiny test set looks like this:

```
0 10
19000 100
20320 10
54540 100
```

My main test file has 56,653,371 ints, of which there are 290,197 sets of ten and four sets of 100. The test machine has an AMD 1090T processor and 8 GB of RAM, and is running GHC 7.8.3 on 64 bit Linux. The only compiler flags used are '-O2 -fflvm'.

There's one important thing to note: I'm intentionally avoiding using counters that are frequently used in programming. For instance, having counters that are tracking the 10's and the 100's: 'if counter one == 100, then...' kind of stuff. I'd like to avoid tracking the state of these counters and use just the available functions/HOF's.

Following is my best attempt so far. It completes the task in 10.1 seconds (**currently at 5.8 seconds**). To put that in perspective, a C version from the thread that I mentioned before finishes in 9.4 seconds. There's another Haskell version that I didn't write that uses counters that completes it 8.1 seconds (**currently at 4.7**). That's my inspiration (thanks Xyne for that and teaching where case statements come into their own).

** EDIT **

I forgot to mention what it does. It splits the input data using interger division into potential ranges of ten and put them into a list of lists (edited to clarify the splitting luqui asked about). So:

```
1 4 7 9                                      -> [1,4,7,9]
1 2 3 8                                      -> [1,2,3,8]
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9                          -> [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 25 27 -> [7,8,9] [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19] [20,25,27]
```

filterLengthBy then removes everything that isn't length 10 because we don't need it. The the resulting list is split into lists of lists based on integer division of the head. So:

```
[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19],[100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109]]
```

becomes:

```
[[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]],[[100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109]]]
```

If the second level of list's length is 10, then there is a match of a range of 100 and is output to the solution set. Otherwise, that list has lists of the range of 10 and should be individually added to the solution set.

**Old version of the code**

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8  as DB
import qualified Data.Function               as DF
import qualified Data.List                   as DL
import Control.Applicative

groupByEqOn :: Eq b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupByEqOn fn = DL.groupBy ((==) `DF.on` fn)

filterLengthBy :: (Int -> Bool) -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
filterLengthBy fn = filter (flb fn)
    where flb fn xs = fn $ length xs   

tensAndHundreds :: [[[Int]]] -> [(Int, Int)]
tensAndHundreds [] = []
tensAndHundreds (x:xs) 
    | length x /= 10 = tens x ++ tensAndHundreds xs
    | otherwise      = (head $ head x, 100) : tensAndHundreds xs

tens :: [[Int]] -> [(Int, Int)]
tens = map (\x -> (head x, 10))

dbEmpty :: DB.ByteString
dbEmpty = DB.empty

dbIntVals :: [DB.ByteString] -> [Int]
dbIntVals [] = []
dbIntVals (x:xs) =
    case (DB.readInt x) of
         (Just (x', dbEmpty)) -> x' : dbIntVals xs
         _                    -> error "*** Error: Non-integer input ***"

generateResults :: [Int] -> [(Int, Int)]
generateResults xs = tensAndHundreds 
                   $ groupByEqOn ((`quot` 100) . head) 
                   $ filterLengthBy (== 10) 
                   $ groupByEqOn (`quot` 10) xs

displayResults :: [(Int, Int)] -> IO ()
displayResults = mapM_ (\(a, b) -> putStrLn (show a ++ " " ++ show b)) 

main :: IO ()
main = dbIntVals <$> DB.lines <$> DB.getContents >>= 
       displayResults . generateResults
```

The only two things that are surprising to me from the profiler is first just how fast filterLengthBy is. Major kudos to all of the people involved for getting filter to be so fast. It's truly a remarkable thing given just how much data that I've thrown at it. For that matter, it's remarkable that what I wrote is as fast as it is. The other surprise is just how slow dbIntVals is. I did implement proper error checking and that makes things a bit slower, but I'm still surprised. Other than that, it seems to read exactly like my code does.

Comment: Thank you: http://imgur.com/8YyN8Mc

Comment: Hmm, I haven't reviewed your code, but would you catch the range of ten `5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14`?

Comment: What happens if you rewrite `dbIntVals` using the `map` function, and change the last line to `displayResults . generateResults . dbIntVals` ?

Comment: So you're already within -6% of the C version performance, and your question is how to make it even faster, have I got that right?

Comment: @luqui

The ranges are all based on 0, even for the tens (0..9, 10..19, 20..29), so the range that you posted is not one that I'm looking for.

Comment: @leftaroundabout

Of course I want as much performance as I can get, so that is part of my question. The bigger thing here is for me to learn to write efficient code in Haskell. Maybe I'm not looking at this quite right, but it seems like memory allocation is a big chunk of the time spent in this code.

Comment: @John L

I originally had mapped DB.readInt and had a simple funtion to extract the value from it and mapped that, and even with full error checking, I picked up some performance having it this way.

Comment: Does `lines` actually do anything useful for you? `DB.readInt` should be able to take care of that for you if you (basically) fold it over the input. Another thing to consider is dropping the lazy IO stuff and using either explicit strict IO or one of those fancy packages like `pipes`.

Comment: dfeuer, I'm sending you one hundred invisible magic jellybeans! The answer to your question about DB.lines is no of course. I wondered why readInt kept the tail and now I know. I'm at 9.2 seconds now and the code is cleaner. I'll refactor the opening post to make it easier to follow. The second part about not being lazy adds much time. The pipes thing I'll look into.

Comment: You might consider switching to [lengthBound](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/list-extras-0.4.1.3/docs/Data-List-Extras-LazyLength.html#v:lengthBound) or [lengthAtLeast](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/utility-ht-0.0.10/docs/Data-List-HT.html#v:lengthAtLeast), if your aversion to counters stems from a need for abstraction; the `length` function unnecessarily (in your case) traverses the whole list, so you might get a performance increase due to early exit from these.

Comment: @AlexR, while you are correct in that `filterLengthBy` function will transverse the whole list, there's nowhere to "short circuit". The length that I'm looking for -- 10 in this case -- will be the entire sublist as they're all 10 or less. Oh yeah, it's also true for just the `length` function as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty much done with this thread. I came here to see what the SO Haskell community had to offer and I got some helpful responses. For that I'm grateful.

The latest version of the code that I posted shows that, given good code, GHC can produce blazing fast, accurate programs using only functional idioms. This may seem obvious, but this is the first Haskell program that I've ever written from scratch (with the obvious copy-and-paste of groupBy).

What did I learn?

From dfeuer I was reminded to be careful of the times when relying only on built in function like map may not necessarily be the best approach. Sometimes it's helpful to combine logic. In this case I got a very significant performance increase.

From applicative I learned about efficient output. The increase of performance was amazing.

If somehow any Haskell/GHC developer is reading this:

In my opinion, groupBy [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/List_function_suggestions#Generalize_groupBy_and_friends) should be included in the standard library and not pushed off to Hackage. Why? It's fast while maintaining accuracy. For the exact same operation over millions of elements and with producing the exact same results, there was a ~8.2% performance increase. I understand that it doesn't do exactly the same thing; I still think that it's worth taking a look at.

Does [this](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_programming_tips#Forget_about_quot_and_rem) actually make any sense? I saw at least a 10% performance increase over the same data set as above with 100% accuracy. I understand that 'rem' and 'mod' do different things and that they tend to round in different "directions", but the former out performs that latter by huge margins. I'm probably not understanding the scope of this, but 10% is pretty hard to ignore.

Comment: I said that I was pretty much done with this, but I did find some significant performance increases. One of them was the dfeuer was correct in that using lazy bytestrings was slowing things down. My initial tests suggested that it wasn't true. I must of have not tested properly. That led me to find that by impleming stricness in the form of $! in one place would yield even better performance. The other was to replace a map with a fold in tens which helped a bit. In the end this fairly inefficient algorithm is running at 5.1 seconds. For a dead horse, it seems to be active still!

Comment: This algorithm has run it's course. Going to strict as apposed to lazy causes issues with memory usage. My final version returns to laziness.

Comment: Wouldn't this kind of question fit better in codereview.stackexchange.com?